# What is the the nature of $(p^p \pm 1)/(p\pm 1)$?

Tags: prime-numbers, congruences

Are twin primes more likely to be centered about $2^{p_i}$ where $p_i$ are the ordered primes?

Let us first define:

$$
(p^p \pm 1)/(p \pm 1) = \prod_{j=1}^{n}q_j,
$$

where

$$
q_j = 1 \bmod p
$$

for every $j$. We now have:

$$q_j = m_jp + 1$$

$$[\prod_{j=1}^n(m_j)(p) + 1)][(p \pm 1)] \mp 1 = p^p,$$

a beautiful start to a [beautiful] mess. $p$ is an odd prime 
$m_j > 1$ since when $m_j = 1$ is such that:

$$
((1)(p) + 1) \nmid (p^p \pm 1)/(p \pm 1).
$$

What is the nature of $n$? What are the restrictions on the value of $n$? 
What values of $m_j$ and how many $m_j$'s are there such that:

$$
((m_j)(p) + 1) || (p^p \pm 1)?
$$

(at least one).

As an exmaple, let's examine the case $p = 7$. $(7^7 + 1)/(7 + 1) = 137,257$ has only two prime factors $29\times4733$. $(7^7 - 1)/(7 - 1) = 102,943$ has only two prime factors: $113\times 911$.

I find it difficult to believe this is novel, although I wish it were.

Comment: What have you attempted in solving the problem thus far?

Comment: A theorem (I found and may be novel) of which this specific question seems appropriate.

Comment: The numbers $2^p\pm1$ are never both prime, except for $p=2$.  So this is very unlikely.  If that's not what you meant, please clarify your question.

Comment: theorem. $q_j = 1   (\bmod p )$ where $(a^p -b^p)/(a-b) =\prod_{j}{q_j}$ for all $j$ where $a$ and $b$ are any coprime nonzero integers and $p\nmid(a-b)$.

Comment: @David oh, I speculated incorrectly based on my result. Thank You, David. Has your statement been proved?

Comment: I forgot to write: $p$ is an odd prime and $q_j$ is an odd prime for every $j$.

Comment: If $p$ is odd then $2^p+1$ is a multiple of $3$.  This rules out all primes except $p=2$.

Comment: @ shoot, yes. oh boy. thanks again David. How can I say the question has been answered?

Comment: 'Both adjacent numbers have much less the number of prime factors' should have been the statement posed as a question.